# Visual Studio - suppress certain "Exception thrown" messages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception

Can you hide "Exception thrown" messages in output for certain methods (certain code areas)?

I use HttpWebRequest for server communication. I periodically check if the server is available (a few times every second). When a server is not reachable HttpWebRequest throws an exception. I catch it and set GUI elements enabled to false. The problem is when the server is unreachable, output window gets cluttered up with "Exception thrown" messages.

I know you can right-click output window and uncheck "Exception Messages". But I am not only one working on the project and there might be someone who wants to see some other exception messages (in their part of the project).

Example of what I need:

```
// Keep showing "Exception thrown" message in this method.
static void Foo()
{
    try
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    catch (NotImplementedException ex)
    {
        // Process exception
    }
}

// Suppress "Exception thrown" message when it is thown in this method.
static void FooSuppress()
{
    try
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // Process exception
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo();
    FooSuppress();
}
```

Current output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in ExceptionTest.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in ExceptionTest.dll
```

Desired output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in ExceptionTest.dll
```

Edit:

Enabling **Just my code** in *Tools/Options/Debugging* might help.

We used Npgsql to access PostgreSQL database and some calls had timeout. Everytime call timeouted "Exception thrown" was written to output window (and there were a lot). **Just my code** prevents that.

Comment: Try #ifdef. With this you can implement conditional exception (you still need to specify exception type though) catching with different configurations.

Comment: I would also like a way to achieve that. That would be awesome if there were some debug attribute or compiler directive to allow you to enable/disable debug outputing of Exceptions in specific areas of our code.

Comment: @Nathan - Visual Studio debugger still *writes the exception message to the output window* (even if you catch it) - the question is how to suppress that output message.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Ah I missed the point... Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

To disable the Exception messages:

(1)Like your previous reply, you could disable it in the Output windows.

(2)You could also disable it under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Output Window.

(3)Or you could just throw the Exception using the Exception Settings under Debug menu->Windows->Exception Settings.

I don't find other workaround to disable it unless you really resolve/handle the Exceptions in your code. I test it using the VS2015 version.

No other good suggestion, but I help you submit a feature here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16752127-visual-studio-suppress-certain-exception-thrown-me

You could vote it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What do you mean by resolve/handle the Exceptions? I still catch it. Do you mean avoid Exceptions altogether?

Comment: @František Němec, Yes, I just mean that capture Exception messages and then avoid them one by one. Of course, I know that maybe it doesn't meet your requirements, just one workaround during debugging:)

Comment: Sadly, I can't do that. I am not the one thowing the exceptions.

Comment: @František Němec, I didn't find other settings in VS IDE could really hide them except my previous lists, I also did some research, find that using blocks can swallow Exceptions, http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/51/c%23-using-blocks-can-swallow-exceptions, but it requires your custom code. Maybe I could help you submit a feature request to the product team:)

Comment: thank you for that link. It's not exactly what i need, but i did not know that and it's definitely good to know. Anyway, thank you for your time and here's the code [link](http://pastebin.com/3a5tmjjC).

Comment: *handling the exceptions* does NOT suppress the message sent to output window. As seen in the question, the code already catches the exceptions.

Comment: This slowed down my debugging to a crawl when I switched to VS Comm. Ed 2022. No issues on 2019; not sure why; either it didn't have these options enabled by default, or its debug printing was just faster. Either way, the program was impossible to debug with a 5+ minute loading time. Disabling exceptions in the output window fixed it. The exceptions were something irrelevant deep inside the .net zip loading anyway. Nothing I could see or affect.

Answer (score -3):

If you are willing to wait a little bit or use a pre-release version, the next version of Visual Studio (VS 15) will have a feature "[Add Conditions to Exception Settings](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes#debuggingdiag)"

> #### Add Conditions to Exception Settings
>
> When you configure the
>   debugger to break on thrown exceptions, you can add conditions so that
>   the debugger will only break when exceptions are thrown in specified
>   modules.
>
> [image: Edit Conditions dialog box]

This will allow you to set filters on when exceptions should break.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not need to break or anything. I just need to hide certain Exception messages that VS prints to output window (not standard output) even when the exception is caught. It's not a big problem because it only affects debugging when someone uses output window and has to search for standard output in a sea of exception messages.

Comment: This *does not* suppress the message being written to the debug output window.