# Is there a way to suppress logging an catched exception in the Console Output?

Tags: c#, exception, console

When debugging on Visual Studio I always watch the opened Console Ouput.
All exceptions will be logged in the output window.

When I catch an expected specific exception, I don't want that this exception will be logged in the output window, because in a cyclic thead the exception will spam this output.
I want to do this programatically. For example I only want to suppress logging the ArgumentException in the method Foo() - but at all other methods and classes the Exception shall be logged.

Is there a way to control for catched exception that this exception will prevented to be locked in the console output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio - suppress certain "Exception thrown" messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127680/visual-studio-suppress-certain-exception-thrown-messages)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956338/visual-studio-2015-how-to-disable-exceptions-outputs

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you looking for?
Debug->Window->ExceptionSettings

Comment: Also that question already was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127680/visual-studio-suppress-certain-exception-thrown-messages

Comment: This is not I was looking for. I want programatically suppress one exception. For example only at a specific method I want to prevent the ArgumentException not to beeing logged.

Comment: Add `catch(ArgumentException){}`. So when it rises nothing's gonna happen. In `Try {} Catch(Exception) {}` structure you can intercept general `Exception` or specific `FileNotFoundException` or yours `ArgumentException`. Also you can add multiple catches.

Comment: Event with catch(ArgumentException){} you got the exception in the Debugging Output.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe you should just check arguments? So they will not rise exception instead of suppressing loggin? Actually i think that what you want is just impossible.