# Visual Studio 2015 How to disable exceptions outputs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, output, runtime-error

I was making a C# application with an update and a draw, and I figured out the update was really slow, although there wasn't any kind of heavy expression.

And after having launched my application independently from Visual Studio, I figured out that it was like 100x faster. The problem was that for every try{} catch {}, VStudio output an error message in the output console. Which made like 100 errors message/ update, which was what slowed down my application.

Now I replaced the try{} by an if(){}, and it works perfectly. Now I'd like to know wether there's a way that VStudio does not output errors in the console, so that I can make try{} statements without freezing my application.

Any idea?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Try something like

```
try {
    // code here
}
except YourException {}
```

Leave `except` block empty if you don't want to take any action. If you want to do something when exception comes, put that inside there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about hiding error logs from Visual Studio's output window when an exception is caught. See Michał Żołnieruk's answer below for the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

You can control whether the exceptions are printed in Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> Exception Messages

[image]