# Preventing Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcpclient

This one has been causing me some bother for a while. I have a TcpClient that runs on a thread and trys to connect to the client

```
                client = new TcpClient();
                client.Connect(m_Hostname, m_PortNum);
```

On failure the Connect function throws a `SocketException` if it cannot connect. Then after say, 10 seconds, it attempts to reconnect. The target client is basically has a listener socket that is only active periodically so it will attempt to reconnect to the target client throughout the lifetime of the program.

The problem is that the message Exception thrown: `'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll` is spat out to the debugger every 10 seconds, each time it cannot connect. It seems there is no real way to prevent this from happening. I thought I could potentially check if the target machine is available first before connecting but I cant see this anywhere.

It seems bad to control program flow using exceptions but I am not sure of another way; worst case I'd like to prevent the exception from printing out in the debugger because it causes unnecessary spam.

Comment: could you use UDP instead. DO you own the other end?

Comment: Yes it needs to be 100% reliable though

Comment: you can layer reliable on top of UDP by sending a message and timeing out on th response. (TCP is build on IP , which is basically UDP) Or you can use a UDP exchange to see if the server is up then open a tcp connection

Comment: The issue is, if you did do a check prior to connecting, it can **still fail**, because networking is unpredictable. If your issue is that the message is printed then I'm not sure you should/could solve it programatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio - suppress certain "Exception thrown" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127680/visual-studio-suppress-certain-exception-thrown-messages)